# HttpURLConnection click

Tags: java

Добрый день, как мне произвести клик по `Input` в `html-коде` c помощи `HttpURLConnection`?

```
input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Логин"
```

Я предполагаю, что это действие можно произвести с помощи `setRequestProperty`, только как ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью HttpURLConnection никак. Можно использовать Headless browser, например Selenium или HtmlUnit. HtmlUnit не способен выполнять сложный js, поэтому рекомендую [Selenium](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.53.1) и к нему [PhantomJsDriver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver/1.1.0)

Так как PhantomJS работает как браузер(только не виден пользователю) к нему надо установить [phantomjs-2.1.1-windows](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) (распаковать из архива на диск)

Вот простенький пример нашел - https://www.appneta.com/blog/automated-testing-java/

Comment: можете привести пример?

Comment: А лучше вот этот урок посмотри, хоть на английском но все довольно просто https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdcOPwFQbtg я и по нему учился

Comment: После работы закрывай driver методом driver.quit() иначе phantomjs.exe будет висеть в диспетчере задач и жрать ОЗУ.

Comment: а если я с компилирую программу и отправлю на другой ПК где нету phantomjs, будет работать ?

Comment: можно в папку с проектом закинуть и все ок будет я думаю